# How to run a CPU-intensive process without preempting normal processes running with normal priority

Tags: linux

It seems that

```
chrt -i 0
```

still preempts normal processes, especially if the process started with chrt is using multiple threads.

Comment: try `man nice` or `man renice` for something already running.

Answer (score 0):

Run in batch mode - https://lwn.net/Articles/3866/

```
chrt -b -p 0 $PID
```